# watch-only addresses doesn't work properly in bitcoind v0.10.0

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, watch-only

I imported a watch-only address to bitcoind by using below command:

```
bitcoin-cli importaddress <myaddress> "testacc" true
```

According to [release notes](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.10.0) it should support some rpc calls for this watch- only address:

> The following RPCs have optional support for watch-only: getbalance, listreceivedbyaddress, listreceivedbyaccount, listtransactions, listaccounts, listsinceblock, gettransaction.

Even it is not written in release notes, i can catch new transactions by calling *listunspent*. But the problem is when i try to call

```
bitcoin-cli listtransactions testacc
```

or

```
bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 0
```

the first call returns an empty array and the result of second call doesn't contains any information about this watch-only address. What may be the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that v0.10.0 is not documented yet, apart from the release notes. Referring to the github repository: [Issue #4045](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/4045)

It appears that a boolean watchonly argument is needed at the end of those commands. Thus below commands would work:

```
bitcoin-cli listtransactions testacc 100 0 true
```

or

```
bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 0 false true [account, includeempty, includewatchonly]
```